# Is it possible to create objects of Enum types in java?

Tags: java

I found this type of code in a repository during my project work.
That repository works well fine... but when i am trying to understand the code through an independent test run... giving error!!!

```
public enum Fruits {
    static {
        APPLE= new Fruits( "APPLE", 0 );
        BANANA = new Fruits( "BANANA", 1 );
       // and so on.
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand the meaning of calling a constructor of enum inside enum, that too without declaring a constructor.

Comment: please elaborate, post your errors

Comment: At least post code that is complete enough to compile.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that this is *actually* the product of decompiling real code. This isn't valid Java source code, but is effectively what the compiler will create for you with an enum of:

```
public enum Fruits {
    APPLE, BANANA;
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, there should also be a constructor declaration in the decompiled code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yes, I'd expect so. It's not really clear where the OP got this code from, or whether there's more.

Comment: You took it very correct... the code WAS decompiled.
I had decompiled the repository...
Thanks...:)

Answer (score 4):

As usual @JonSkeets's intuition wins out.  Compiling the code he provided:

```
public enum Fruits {
  APPLE, BANANA;
}
```

Then decompiling with `jad` yields:

```
public final class Fruits extends Enum
{

    public static Fruits[] values()
    {
        return (Fruits[])$VALUES.clone();
    }

    public static Fruits valueOf(String s)
    {
        return (Fruits)Enum.valueOf(Fruits, s);
    }

    private Fruits(String s, int i)
    {
        super(s, i);
    }

    public static final Fruits APPLE;
    public static final Fruits BANANA;
    private static final Fruits $VALUES[];

    static
    {
        APPLE = new Fruits("APPLE", 0);
        BANANA = new Fruits("BANANA", 1);
        $VALUES = (new Fruits[] {
            APPLE, BANANA
        });
    }
}
```

The complete example illustrates all of the work the compiler is doing for you when you declare an enum.  Note that, as @MarkoTopolnik points out, you can't do this yourself, simply because the compiler will not allow it.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public enum Fruits {
        APPLE("APPLE", 0 ), BANANA("BANANA", 1 );
        String text;
        int value;
        private Fruits(String text, int value){
             this.text = text;
             this.value = value;
        }
        public String getText(){
             return text;
        }
        public int getValue(){
             return value;
        }
    }
```

This concept is useful when you wish to add more parameters.

Comment: Actually, those are implicit arguments to an implicit enum member constructor. They set the *name* and *ordinal* properties.

Comment: Yeah both of those properties are available on all enums automatically.  It would be a complete waste of time to include them in a constructor.

Comment: Agree but this helps understanding the concept of constructor and value retrieval. If OP wants to add more parameters in the constructor, it will be very useful